# Flash How do flush or empty netstream buffer

Tags: actionscript-3, buffer, netstream

I'm experiencing an issue with a 20 video Flash project. We're calling the videos from a local source, and FLVPlayback is opening netstreams and generating this huge Uncategorized chunk of memory. Upon further inspection, it turns out that it's a large amount of netstream buffers. How do I empty these buffers?

I've found this `NetStream.Buffer.Empty` but I'm not sure how to properly use it.

Comment: I can't help you with the actual question, but I can tell you that `NetStream.Buffer.Empty` is a status of a `NetStream`, not a method you can call. You can occasionally see it when a video runs out of buffer in a status event. There is no way to "properly use it" since it is not an action.

Comment: You can use the `dispose()` method of a NetStream to free it from memory

Comment: Or, if you don't want to dispose the netstream, you can set it's `bufferTime` to `0`.

Comment: I'm now using this to empty the NetStream buffers `var vp: VideoPlayer = flvPlayer.getVideoPlayer(flvPlayer.activeVideoPlayerIndex);
 vp.netStream.dispose(); // Used to be close();`

Comment: @Batman You answered my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `close();` I used `dispose();` to stop, close, and flush the NetStream buffer. Many thanks to @batman

`netStream.dispose()`